# Rotate the Points on a Plane $P = ax+by+cz + d = 0$ parallel to $z = 0$ plane

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, 3d, computational-geometry

I have a plane $P = ax+by+cz + d = 0$ and many points on that plane.

I want to rotate $P$ so that it becomes parallel to $z = 0$ plane.
Which method should I use? 
I know that the normal vector of my plane is $(a,b,c)$. But I couldn't handle the operations. Can you help me?

@alex.jordan I could not comment since the character limitations. When I display my points, I see that they still have z coordinates.
Here are some examples:

```
Points in:
(0.185237, 0.000000, 3.213694)
(2.811481, 0.000000, 5.276483)
(9.036226, 0.000000, 3.038835)
(0.231554, 0.000000, 8.820473)
Points out:
(-0.000000, 3.213694, 0.185237)
(-0.000000, 5.276483, 2.811481)
(-0.000000, 3.038835, 9.036226)
(-0.000000, 8.820473, 0.231554)

Points in:
(2.936906, 6.026721, 5.531595)
Points out:
(-4.910498, 6.153035, 3.684087)

Points in:
(0.038637, 2.216165, 1.576430)
(4.368976, 3.383844, 5.036302)
Points out:
(1.936124, 1.894746, 0.243656)
(2.626620, 4.911774, 4.987788)

Points in:
(0.870159, 2.345252, 3.526318)
Points out:
(2.346639, 0.044205, 3.630928)

Points in:
(2.296563, 3.377942, 4.388633)
(3.367447, 8.511868, 4.610036)
Points out:
(1.851119, 3.250218, 4.685534)
(3.252196, 8.294517, 5.066384)
```

I paste my code here:

```
public static List<Point3d> rotateToXY(List<Point3d> pointList, Equation eq)
    {

        List<Point3d> points = new ArrayList<>();
        double theta = Math.atan((eq.b/eq.a));
        double phi = Math.atan(eq.c/ (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(eq.a, 2)+ Math.pow(eq.b,2)) ));

        double sinT = Math.sin(-1*theta);
        double cosT = Math.cos(-1*theta);

        double sinP = Math.sin((Math.PI/2) - phi);
        double cosP = Math.cos((Math.PI/2) - phi);
        double[][] rotateAboutZaxis =
            {
                {cosT, (-1)*sinT, 0},
                {sinT,  cosT, 0},
                {0,0,1}
            };

        double[][] rotateAboutYaxis =
            {
                {sinP, 0, -1*sinP},
                {0, 1, 0},
                {sinP, 0, cosP}
            };
        Matrix rotateY = new Matrix(rotateAboutYaxis);
        Matrix rotateZ = new Matrix(rotateAboutZaxis);
        Matrix rotateYZ = rotateY.times(rotateZ);
        for(Point3d p: pointList)
        {
            double[][] pointCoordinates = {{p.x}, {p.y}, {p.z}};
            Matrix coordinates = new Matrix(pointCoordinates);
            coordinates = rotateYZ.times(coordinates);
            points.add(new Point3d(coordinates.getRowPackedCopy()));
        }
        return points;
    }
```

Where am I mistaken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need any special orthogonal transformation that takes the unit vector $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}(a,b,c)$ to $(0,0,1)$.

In spherical coordinates, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}(a,b,c)$ is equal to $\big(\cos(\theta)\cos(\varphi),\sin(\theta)\cos(\varphi),\sin(\varphi)\big)$ for longitude $\theta$ and latitude $\varphi$. To find $\theta$ and $\varphi$ in terms of $a$, $b$, and $c$ depends on which octant the point is in, since inverse trig functions are involved. But if the point is in the "first" octant, then $\theta=\arctan(b/a)$ and $\varphi=\arctan\left(\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)$.

You can then rotate the point to be in the $xz$-plane using rotation by $-\theta$ about the $z$-axis:$$\begin{bmatrix}\cos(-\theta)&-\sin(-\theta)&0\\\sin(-\theta)&\cos(-\theta)&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ and then rotate the result up to the $z$-axis using rotation by $\frac{\pi}{2}-\varphi$ about the $y$-axis:
$$\begin{bmatrix}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\varphi\right)&0&-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\varphi\right)\\0&1&0\\\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\varphi\right)&0&\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\varphi\right)\end{bmatrix}$$

In summary, first find $\theta$ and $\varphi$. Then compute $$\begin{bmatrix}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\varphi\right)&0&-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\varphi\right)\\0&1&0\\\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\varphi\right)&0&\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\varphi\right)\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\cos(-\theta)&-\sin(-\theta)&0\\\sin(-\theta)&\cos(-\theta)&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$$
and you wind up on the $z$-axis. If $(x,y,z)$ were a point somewhere on the original plane, then $$\begin{bmatrix}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\varphi\right)&0&-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\varphi\right)\\0&1&0\\\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\varphi\right)&0&\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\varphi\right)\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\cos(-\theta)&-\sin(-\theta)&0\\\sin(-\theta)&\cos(-\theta)&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}$$ will correspondingly move that point to the $xy$-plane.

---

Following OP's attempt to apply this, edited into the question:

You tried:
$$\begin{align}
(0.185237, 0.000000, 3.213694)\\
(2.811481, 0.000000, 5.276483)\\
(9.036226, 0.000000, 3.038835)
\end{align}$$
which I guess implies that the plane is $0x+y+0z=0$. With $(a,b,c)=(0,1,0)$, we have $\theta=\pi/2$ and $\varphi=0$. So the matrices above are 
$$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&-1\\0&1&0\\1&0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\-1&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&-1\\-1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}-z\\-x\\y\end{bmatrix}$$

For your points, this gives
$$\begin{align}
(-3.213694, -0.185237, 0.000000)\\
(-5.276483, -2.811481, 0.000000)\\
(-3.038835, -9.036226, 0.000000)
\end{align}$$

Comment: I tried this method but my plane is not projected to xy-axis. Instead, I get my points in 3D and my plane stretched. What would be the reason for that?

Comment: Projected? I thought this was about rotatin the points onto the $xy$-plane, not projecting them. But maybe you don't mean 'projected'. What are you plotting with? These matrices are special orthogonal, so they could never change a point's distance from the origin. Sometimes, some graphing applications do not use equal scales in the various directions unless you specify. And that could cause an appearance of stretching. Also, just to check, do you feel comfortable with the matrix multiplication?

Comment: I have written an answer. Could you check it please?

Comment: I have edited my original post.

Comment: There is no way to project a 3 dimensional plane into a 2 dimensional plane that preserves distance.

Comment: @user112790 That is not what OP is trying to do. OP is trying to rotate points in a certain 2D plane that is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ over to the $xy$-plane.

Comment: @cagirici I followed the method through with your first set of points, and it does indeed take the points to the $z=0$ plane.

Comment: I used the wrong word "project". btw, I have inserted my code. Could you check it please?